# Using T-comma (Ț) in where-clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a user record in my SQL Server DB with accented characters in their last name. The name is `ȚÎRA`, that is T-comma (U+021A), I-circumflex(U+00CE), R and A.

Regardless of what I try I can't figure out how to search for that name and that name alone. Here's some details and what I've tried:

```
Changed database context to 'mdb'.
1> SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'mdb'
2> GO
name    collation_name
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mdb     Latin1_General_CI_AI

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = 0x31BE7DEA327AF1439045420F87E036B2
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?IRA

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE last_name = 'ȚÎRA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE last_name = 'TIRA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = 0x31BE7DEA327AF1439045420F87E036B2 AND last_name LIKE '%RA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?IRA

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = 0x31BE7DEA327AF1439045420F87E036B2 AND last_name LIKE '__RA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = 0x31BE7DEA327AF1439045420F87E036B2 AND last_name LIKE '%IRA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?IRA

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT last_name FROM ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = 0x31BE7DEA327AF1439045420F87E036B2 AND last_name LIKE '_IRA'
2> GO
last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 rows affected)
```

The ? in the sqlcmd output is just my console, SQL management studio outputs the character just fine so I'm not worried about it.

I think I've ruled out the I-circumflex being the issue and as you can see I can't make the single character wildcard hit the T-comma, nor can I search for it in the literal form or relying to accent insensitivity. I can't touch the collation as the application that uses this data requires the collation shown above.

The T-comma is the only one I've found not to work, umlauts, accents in French names and even C-cedillas work just fine. Is there any way to make the searches hit the T-comma? This is causing issues to our service desk staff as they don't find the user with a normal search and I'm wondering if I just need to dumb-down the data and replace all non-ASCII characters with ASCII to make it work. Would be a real pity as we finally started using non-dumbed data and were happy to see the "usual" accents I mentioned were handled without issues.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but I assume that `last_name` is `NVARCHAR` (or another Unicode-type column)?

Comment: `N'ȚÎRA'` not `'ȚÎRA'`.

Comment: @Martin
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME
ca_contact last_name -9 nvarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just due to the way you handling the Unicode-literal string `'ȚÎRA'`.

Consider the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (last_name NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (N'ȚÎRA')
SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE last_name = 'ȚÎRA'
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

This outputs no results.

However, if you seearch for `N'ȚÎRA'`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (last_name NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (N'ȚÎRA')
SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE last_name = N'ȚÎRA'
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

You get your result.  The `N` makes it a Unicode string literal.

Comment: On the DB level this works, but my issue is the application where this data comes from has two layers of translation between the UI and the actual DB to make the app DB agnostic and I have no access to modify those layers. Looks like I have to take this to the software vendor and hope they treat this as a bug instead of improvement idea.

Comment: @JussiV That sounds like a bug to me, if it's not correctly handling Unicode-strings in the search criteria.  Hopefully you manage to get it resolved with them